# Android alarm can't be canceled from another activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I make an application an adding alarm function in my application.
I put the code to activate alarm in different activity with the code for cancel, The alarm can active in the time that I set from Tambah_To_Do_List Activity, but The alarm can't canceled from Daftar_To_Do_List activity.

I have tried some same question for cancel android alarm from stackoverflow, but no one is work for mycode.

Here is the code of Tambah_To_Do_List Activity :

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Tambah_To_Do_List extends Activity {

private OperasiDatabaseToDoList oprDatabasetdl = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private EditText txttdid;
private EditText txtact;
private DatePicker weddingdate;
private TimePicker weddingtime;
private Button btnsimpan;
private Boolean data_baru;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String tdid ="";
    String activity ="";

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tambah_to_do_list);

    oprDatabasetdl = new OperasiDatabaseToDoList(this);  
    db = oprDatabasetdl.getWritableDatabase();  
    oprDatabasetdl.createTable(db);

    Intent sender = getIntent();
    String status = sender.getExtras().getString("status");
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("baru")){
        data_baru = true;
    } else
    {
        data_baru = false;
        tdid = sender.getExtras().getString("tdid");
        activity = sender.getExtras().getString("activity");


    }

    txttdid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txttdid);
    txttdid.setText(tdid);
    txtact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtact);
    txtact.setText(activity);
    weddingdate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.weddingdate);
    weddingtime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.weddingtime);
 /**   final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int days = Integer.parseInt(day);
    int months = Integer.parseInt(month);
    int years = Integer.parseInt(year);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, days);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, months);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, years); */

    btnsimpan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsimpan);
    if(data_baru==true)
        btnsimpan.setText("Simpan"); 
    else 
        btnsimpan.setText("Edit");
    btnsimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
              simpandata();
            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,weddingdate.getDayOfMonth());
            calSet.set(Calendar.MONTH,weddingdate.getMonth());
            calSet.set(Calendar.YEAR,weddingdate.getYear());
            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, weddingtime.getCurrentHour());
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, weddingtime.getCurrentMinute());
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);

        }  
    });  
}

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast.makeText(context, "\n\n***\n"
            + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
            + "***\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Here is the code of Daftar_To_Do_List activity :

```
package com.willis.weddingmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Daftar_To_Do_List extends Activity {
private OperasiDatabaseToDoList oprDatabasetdl = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private Cursor dbCursor = null;  
private Button btnhapusemua;
private Button btnhapus;
private Button btnedit;
private Button btnrefresh;
private Button btnmatikan;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;

//private LinearLayout lineartambah;
private String tdid, activity, day, month, year,hour,minute;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.daftar_to_do_list);
    oprDatabasetdl = new OperasiDatabaseToDoList(this);  
    db = oprDatabasetdl.getWritableDatabase();  
    oprDatabasetdl.createTable(db);
    TampilkanData();
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    btnhapusemua = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnhapusemua);
    btnhapusemua.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.setTitle("Konfirmasi");
            dialog.setMessage("Anda yakin akan menghapus seluruh data?");
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                    oprDatabasetdl.deleteAllDataToDoList(db);
                    TampilkanData();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }  
    });  


    btnmatikan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmatikan);
    btnmatikan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.setTitle("Konfirmasi Alarm");
            dialog.setMessage("Anda yakin akan mematikan alarm?");
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }  
    });
```